# Advice on Apache / WordPress / Adaptive Images

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use Matt Wilcox's Adaptive Images (adaptive-images.com) on my WordPress site but I'm having trouble... I've tried troubleshooting with Matt but without success.

I'm running WordPress 3.4.1 on a completely new, clean install. No plug-ins, nothing, just the Twenty Eleven theme straight out of the box. It's installed in the root, not in a subfolder. I haven't set pretty permalinks so WP hasn't generated a .htaccess file.

I've added the AI .htaccess and adaptive-images.php files (both unchanged, initially) from AI 1.5.2 to the root of my WP installation. I've added the required JS to the header.php file.

On loading the page, I get missing images for every image on the page. I've followed the thread here - https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/issues/32 - but the images are still missing and I don't get a black image with an error message. My images all return a 404.

I've attempted to follow the guidance in https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/issues/18 but without success.

The ai-cache folder is not generated. I've tried creating it manually with permissions of 755 and 777 but nothing writes into the folder.

I've manually changed the JS to 'document.cookie='resolution=480; path=/';' to simulate a mobile device screen size but no bananas.

I've looked at what feels like every article ever written on AI and WordPress. It seems that some people can get happily get it to work; others not. What I haven't been able to find is a definitive solution from anyone on how to make it work.

As per the instructions.htm file in the AI download I have tried to do some reading up on how to use mod_rewrite - though I haven't been able to find an answer. It would *seem* that the problem may be related to my server config - but that's really beyond my sphere of knowledge.

Any guidance or assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've also been trying to implement Adaptive Images into Wordpress - turns out some one has already made a plugin of it: https://github.com/JorgenScott/WP-Resolutions

Not had chance to try it out myself yet and strangely plugin is not listed in codex.

Also take a look here:
https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/issues/10
https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/issues/22